# PyTeleBot / Schedule - Send msg at certain time

Tags: python, telegram, schedule, python-telegram-bot

everyone.
I use PyTeleBot and Schedule to do some stuff, now I need to send a message at 00:00 everyday. I set up Schedule with bot.polling already, btw.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
**def job(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "2")**

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    some code
def runBot():
    bot.polling()

def runSchedulers():
    schedule.every(00:00).do(job)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=runBot)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=runSchedulers)
    # starting thread 1 
    t1.start() 
    # starting thread 2 
    t2.start()
```

**TypeError: job() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'**

Thanks in advance

Comment: To send a message you need the chat.id to whoever you're going to message. Where does your job() get that information when you schedule it?

Comment: Lol, that was an anwkard question to ask, ty